# Asking whether answers to an old question are still relevant?

Tags: support, old-questions

I'm interested in this question:

[Is there a recommended package for machine learning in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289920/is-there-a-recommended-package-for-machine-learning-in-python)

Although the answers look good, they were posted about two years ago, so I'm afraid they may no longer be relevant.

What is the recommended course of action?

Note: **can someone please answer my actual (meta) question without focusing on the particular SO question I linked to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel that asking a new question on SO isn't going to go well, or is not useful to the site, you could use the chat feature to get the opinions of users regarding the older question.  If you then find that answers in the original question are out of date you can edit the question to improve it's value or flag it for moderation if you do not have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Asking the question again would probably be the best solution, but I'd be afraid to see it closed as duplicate with no question asked by a few overzealous mods. I think this is going to be more and more relevant as SO ages. Maybe allowing duplicates (or rather, disallowing closing as a duplicate of an old question) would be a good solution?

Comment: I think that the old questions should be edited to reflect that they are specific to a point in time and that more up to date answers exist, but only where the newer question and answers are of the sort welcomed on the site. There is no need to create updated shopping lists.

Comment: The problem is that I don't *know* if more up-to-date answers exist...

Comment: Let's leave aside the "shopping list" problem, I feel very strongly about this issue (I find them very useful) and this topic could degenerate quickly :)

Comment: If the question, "do more up-to-date answers exist" can be answered yes or no then you'll probably get an answer, even if the question is closed or marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, these type of questions aren't accepted on StackOverflow anymore.  They aren't definitively answerable, they are localized (as you are experiencing) to a moment of time...

Essentially, these questions are [shopping recommendations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which are not a good fit for StackOverflow, or any other site on the network.

Comment: Silly old me didn't see the questions content, I will erase my answer.

Comment: How sad and stupid.

Comment: @user139018: I'd suggest you plead your case for changing this rule, but I don't think it would result in much, coming from a new user who hasn't even bothered to fill in their profile.

Comment: I've been there long enough to know that there is no point in trying to reason the high-rep users to open-up their world view and actually try to make the site more useful to many people.

Comment: Note that you didn't even answer my question. Even if this particular question may no longer be asked, what should one do when an old question's answer may no longer be relevant?

Comment: @user139018: The answer is that these questions aren't accepted here, so there is nothing to do.  Part of the problem is determining if an answer is no longer relevant.  With tens of thousands of answers to questions like this, who is going to maintain them?  Even if you were to flag, how would a moderator know if the answer is no longer relevant?  Its a losing battle.  With enough reputation, a user can still comment on an answer to point out failings.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. When I stumble on a old question that potentially answers my problem, what can I do to ask other people if the answers are still relevant?

Comment: @user139018: Can you leave a comment on the answer?  Like anything else, you need enough rep to do so, and there is no guarantee that the user will respond...

Comment: That would give me a very, very low chance of ever getting an answer...